# Does the Euler equation imply an absolute value for internal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

In thermodynamics, the Euler equation is

$$
U=TS-PV+\mu N
$$

Given the temperature, entropy, pressure, volume, electrical potential, and number of moles of a system, this seems to imply that I could calculate *the* internal energy of the system.

Similarly, the internal energy of an ideal gas is given as

$$
U=\frac{3}{2}N k_B T
$$

However, I thought that internal energy was only defined up to a reference value.

For example, in *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics* by Herbert Callen, it says

> Only differences in energy, rather than absolute values of the energy, have physical significance, either at the atomic level or in macroscopic systems. It is conventional therefore to adopt some particular state of a system ... which is taken as zero.

What am I misunderstanding here?

---

My question is very related to [How can $U$ have an arbitrary zero point and still be extensive?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581606/how-can-u-have-an-arbitrary-zero-point-and-still-be-extensive), but after reading all the answers, I do think we are asking different things (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: I think that the point here is that we _decided_ to define the U = 0 ("zero energy") point as the condition in which the gas has T = 0, so that a more general definition of internal energy would also include "+ a constant" that was arbitrarily set to zero, much like for potential energies in mechanics. 
But, maybe, my vision is too naive and the problem is more subtle than this...

Comment: $\mu$, the chemical potential, also has no absolute reference zero. I agree with Alessio that one of the idealizations of the ideal gas model is that the energy is set to zero at $T=0$. So neither of these points contradict the general fact that energy has only relative meaning.  See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/722437/isnt-energy-absolute-according-to-thermodynamics/722451#722451).

Comment: See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/722437/isnt-energy-absolute-according-to-thermodynamics?noredirect=1&lq=1). It tackles the same question.